# how to delete the colliders of the player and assign exactly the same coliders after a few seconds in unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am new to unity and i am trying to do a similar death animation to Mario
in order to do that, i want to delete the colliders of the player
let him fall and when he reached a certain y teleport him to the start 
and return his colliders

i don't know how to return the exact colliders
i am using box collider for the body of the player and a circle collider for his lags so i cant use only

```
gameObject.AddComponent<"BoxCollider2D">();

gameObject.AddComponent <"CircleCollider2D">();
```

help will be appraised

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get the Collider2D and disable it rather than removing it like this:

```
GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to deactivate the collider when the player dies to create the "falling" animation (No colliders anymore, so the player is falling through the ground).
Your player should already have those colliders, I suggest you to only use a BoxCollider2D it will be easier.

You need to setup the BoxCollider2D in the inspector. In your code, you are about to deactivate this component when the player dies, you can use `GetComponent` to achieve this. So it would look like this:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
```

See the full documentation of this Class [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider2D.html)

You can then check the position of your player to "reset" it by getting the Transform component.

Edit: Furthermore, you shouldn't have any `addComponent` in your code in order to do this

Comment: Great, please mark this topic as resolved so it’s clear. Regards